# Form not working after update jquery from 3.3.1-min to 3.5.1

Tags: jquery

I have a form which was working fine with jquery-3.3.1.min.js
Now I would like to work with bootstrap and jquery-3.5.1.js but the form is not working.
With both files is working the form but bootstrap has some problem.

My code to send the email is as follow:

```
    // Contact form
var form = $('#main-contact-form');
var button = $('.btn-flat');
form.submit(function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    var form_status = $('<div class="form_status"></div>');
    var data_to_send = {};
    $("form .col-sm-12").each(function(){
        data_to_send[$(this).find(".form-control").attr("name")] = $(this).find(".form-control").val();
    });

    $.ajax({
        url: $(this).attr('action'),
        method: "POST",
        data: data_to_send,
        beforeSend: function(){
            form.prepend( form_status.html('<p style="padding:10px;"><i class="fa fa-spinner fa-spin"></i> Sending ...</p>').fadeIn() );
        }
    }).done(function(data){
        form_status.html('<p class="text-success">' + data.message + '</p>');
        if(data.type=="success"){
            $(button).hide(500);
            $("form .col-sm-12").hide(500);
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: What errors are you getting in the console?

Comment: Please edit and click `[<>]` snippet editor and prepare a [mcve]